# Muslim girl hired to be a superhero on TV and beat up thugs on the street

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv, super-hero, female-characters

A few years ago I saw a trailer for this new superhero movie (not DC or Marvel). It was about a reality TV showrunner who found a muslim girl who is good at fighting and wanted to make her a superhero TV star. They gave her a black ninja like suit with a hood and a simple superhero name like fighting angel or avenger or something. Then followed her around with cameras as she beats up crooks on the street.

I don't remember anything else. And no, I'm sure that it wasn't Ms. Marvel.

Comment: Might have been promotional stuff for The Boys. They have several fake newsreports/trailers to promote their show.

Comment: Is this a superhero setting with actual superpowers and/or magic/psychic/etc or is this more like *Kick Ass* where it's just people using mundane weapons and brawling?

Comment: [Looks like you found your answer!](https://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmytongue/comments/12stp5i/tomtmovie_muslim_girl_hired_to_be_a_superhero_on/) Don't forget to add it as an answer here and accept :)

Comment: Although, if so, it sounds like it may be off brand for the site, although we have had borderline examples for superheroes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Valentine: The Dark Avenger](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt5305352/)

Someone [found it](https://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmytongue/comments/12stp5i/tomtmovie_muslim_girl_hired_to_be_a_superhero_on/) for me! It's an indonesian superhero film from 2017. I got most of the things right except that the heroine is not muslim, but indonesian. For some reason I wrongly remembered that they replace her hijab with a hood on her superhero costume.

Comment: I would suggest to reference the Reddit answer that actually helped you, although I don't know if there is an actual policy, or what the other members of the site would believe is best.

Comment: @Clockwork - There's no policy, but it's certainly polite to credit those that assisted you

Comment: FWIW, [Indonesia is about 7/8ths Muslim](https://www.cia.gov/the-world-factbook/countries/indonesia/#people-and-society).

Comment: "the heroine is not muslim, but indonesian". You know those are not related right? She could be both. Given that most Indonesians are muslim the chance is high that she actually is muslim